# Italicize lines that fit regular expressions VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am programming in rust using vscode and I want to italicize lines that fit a regular expression. For example:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn integrator_chain_new() {
        // code
    }
}
```

I want the annotation lines that take the form `#[something...]`.The regular expression for matching these lines would look something like `\s*#\[.*\]\n`.

Is there functionality in vscode to match these lines and italicize them?

Comment: How do you italicize something in VS code?  You are really asking for a second thing here, on top of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension that can do this: [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight).  For example, in your settings.json:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

    "(//\\s*)(\\sTODO\\s)(\\s*:?)(.*)": [
      {},
      {
        // "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
        "backgroundColor": "#777",
        "color": "#000",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "fontStyle": "italic",
        "borderRadius": "3px"
      },
      {},
      {
        "color": "#fff",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
      }
    ]
  },
```

results in this:

[image]

It will override your usual syntax highlighting.

I tested it with a `\\n` in the middle of one and it worked.  Note the double escapes, including the `#` sign.

---

This seems to work on your code:

```
"highlight.regexes": {

    "(\\s*)(\\#\\[.*?\\]\\n)": [

      {},
      {
        "color": "#fff",          // I left this in just to make it more obvious
        // "fontWeight": "bold",
        "fontStyle": "italic",
      }
    ]
  },
```

You will probably have to **reload** vscode after making this setting change.